# Making a new frame and decorate it using the SpringLayout using SpringUtilities

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, springlayout

I am currently making a small application which i need the Spring Utilities class for, this class Extends 'JPanel' because it is a content pane, however i need to get the type of layout through a container, but only this class/frame is using the spring layout, which returns an EventQueue Exception
(class = https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/SpringGridProject/src/layout/SpringUtilities.java)
The error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 0
at java.awt.Container.getComponent(Unknown Source)
at dinges.Utilities.SpringUtilities.getConstraintsForCell(SpringUtilities.java:153)
at dinges.Utilities.SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(SpringUtilities.java:190)
at dinges.Containers.Addnew.<init>(Addnew.java:38)
at dinges.Containers.Listeners.AddListener.mousePressed(AddListener.java:27)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I think that it is due to this

```
SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(this, 3, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6);
```

Because 'this' cannot be used, but i am unsure what to use then.

Code:

```
    package dinges.Containers;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;

import dinges.Utilities.SpringUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Addnew extends JPanel {

    /**
     *  > Add a text input for the following:
     *  > Id, Name, last name, current balance, and the state. But this has to be in order of the new Account.
     *  > we're just going to be using JTextFields, a JButton for saving and JLabels for writing what it is
     * 
     **/

    public Addnew() {
        // frame size is WIDTH =   280     ,      HEIGHT =     480
        SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
        setLayout(layout);

        JButton save = new JButton("Save data");
        JTextField name = new JTextField(15);
        JTextField lastname = new JTextField(15);
        JComboBox<String> accounttype = new JComboBox<String>();
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("First name: ", JLabel.TRAILING);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Last name: ", JLabel.TRAILING);
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Account type: ", JLabel.TRAILING);
        label1.setLabelFor(name);
        label2.setLabelFor(lastname);
        label3.setLabelFor(accounttype);

        SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(this, 3, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6);




        add(label1);
        add(label2);
        add(label3);
        add(save);
        add(name);
        add(lastname);
        add(accounttype);
    }

}
```

Any help would be great, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add components to the container first. Then apply `SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid()` method as it is trying to layout existing components. So just move `makeCompactGrid()` to the end of `Addnew()` constructor after all `add()` were executed.

As a side note, even though SpringLayout is very flexible, it is very low level as well, and usually used by GUI builds, and can be cumbersome to code by hand. See [How to Use SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) for more details:

> SpringLayout is a very flexible layout manager that can emulate many
>   of the features of other layout managers. SpringLayout is, however,
>   very low-level and as such you really should only use it with a GUI
>   builder, rather than attempting to code a spring layout manager by
>   hand.